# Hide extra buttons on overflow

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Here I am showing the filters applied to the results, the selected would be active, rest won't be active. But if the results are exceeding that one line, I need to create an hide/show button for other ones, which would be dynamic and dependent on the number of filters.

For ex:

```
<button>Filter 1</button><button>Filter 2</button><button>Filter 3</button><button (click)="showAll()">+2 more</button>
```

When I click on +2 more it should show the remaining two. If there are just 3 then +2 more will not be there.

In this case how to use the `overflow:hidden`?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 button-row">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary"selected>{{selectedFilter.name}}</button>
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary"selected *ngFor="let subject of selectedFilter.listOfFilters" [ngClass]="{'active':subject===selectedFilter.selected}">{{subject}}</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for `overflow:hidden` to work you would probably need to set a static height on the button container that has `overflow:hidden` set. It also looks like your buttons are floating left in a row and not stacked vertically

Comment: i have updated the example, it automatically made them vertical when i was writing, plus the div.row works good instead of mat-action-row

Comment: i need to hide the extra buttons created during *ngFor="let subject of selectedFilter.listOfFilters"